# Question about a possible error of the book

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

We consider the follow Dirichlet problem
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle \begin{cases} -\Delta u =f & \Omega \\ u=0 & \partial \Omega  \end{cases}
\end{align*}
were $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded open. ($\star$) It is known that for this problem there exists a unique weak solution $u \in H_{0}^1(\Omega)$ for each $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ fixed, and operator
\begin{align*}
\Delta^{-1} : f \in L^2(\Omega) \longmapsto u \in H_{0}^1(\Omega)
\end{align*}
is continuous. Now it can be shown that $(-\Delta)^{-1}$ is compact injective self-adjoint operator on $L^2(\Omega)$ and $H_{0}^1(\Omega)$. Ok, I'm not interested to prove that it is compact and self-adjoint. In the book, in the demonstration said that $\Delta^{-1} : f \in L^2(\Omega) \longmapsto u \in H_{0}^1(\Omega)$ is bijective by result in ($\star$).

It seems to me that it should be only injective operator, and not bijective. Is it a book error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can show that for $f\in L^2(\Omega)$, we have $\Delta^{-1} f\in H_0^1(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega)$, therefore, for any $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)\setminus H^2(\Omega)$, there is no $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ with $\Delta^{-1}f=u$.

On the other hand, if one replace $L^2(\Omega)$ by $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ then, $\Delta^{-1}: H^{-1}(\Omega)\to H_0^1(\Omega)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Ok, then it is correct that in reference to the result ($\star$) we can only say that $\Delta^{-1} : f \in L^2(\Omega) \longmapsto u \in H_{0}^1(\Omega)$ is injective and not bijective, right?

Comment: Yes @JohnMartin.

Comment: To be more precise, you only get the $H^2(\Omega)$ inclusion if $\partial \Omega$ is sufficiently regular.  Lipschitz is not enough: we need something like $C^{1,1}$.

Comment: You are right @Glitch. Note also that even in the general case, we still have $H_{loc}^2(\Omega)$ regularity, so in all cases $\Delta^{-1}$ is not bijective.